# safely interrupt ntfs-3g write stuck at less than 100kB/s

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I'm trying to copy about 20 GB of data, some big files and some directories with many small files, from my laptop to an NTFS formatted hard drive in my desktop on the same network. I figured just using a recursive `scp` to copy everything over should be fine but after a few minutes the copy slowed down to less than 100kB/s.

I've had this problem before when copying many small files using ntfs-3g, and I've resolved it before by copying a big tar archive instead, so I thought I'd cancel the `scp`, and try that after remounting the drive. I ran `unmount /dev/sdb1` about 45 minutes ago and it hasn't finished. `/proc/meminfo` shows `Dirty: 4659808 kB` and it's *very slowly* going down.

I'd rather not wait 12 hours but I'm worried that interrupting the unmount or force resetting my computer will corrupt more than just the files I'm copying right now. What is the safest way to cancel the remaining writes?

Comment: Have you considered using NTFS3 instead of ntfs-3g?

Comment: @Ramhound I've used NTFS3 before but had some issues so I went back to ntfs-3g, I don't remember what those issues were though and I might try using it again in the near future.